# Magento 2 get Parent products id in admin create products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

how to get Parent id of the child products magento 2 in create product admin?

Thanks

Comment: You want ids of configurable product, where do you want this?

Comment: hello @Anime can you please check the updated question i want id on create products admin

Answer (score 1):

> Try to use following method for configurable associated products.

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Helper;


class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
/**
*@var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable
*/
protected $configurable;

public function __construct(
\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable
){
$this->_configurable = $configurable;
}


public function getParent($product) {
  $getParent = $this->_configurable->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
  echo "<pre>"; print_r($getParent); exit;
}
```

Comment: how to get product bundle id from child?

Comment: @huykon225 try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/348580/82670